# How to download and install Echidna?

Tags: solidity, web3js, security, tools, slither

I have just started learning echidna but i havent found any detailed information of how to install and setup echidna in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-built binaries for Echidna are available on its [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/crytic/echidna/releases).

Installing Echidna for WSL is the same as installing for Linux:

1. Download the latest pre-built Linux binary from the releases page
2. Unzip it
3. Move `echidna` to one of the folders on your `$PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`)

Echidna also provides experimental Windows binaries [since version 2.1.0](https://github.com/crytic/echidna/releases/tag/v2.1.0) so you can also try directly using Echidna on Windows instead of through WSL.